# Android: multiple user can not purchase same in-App Purchase item using same device

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

- Is there a way to do For example. x user purchases - package No1 and y user want to purchase package No1 again from same device ? is google in app purchase item  managed in app purchase ? i try to do this but it not show purchases dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below link, If your in app purchase type is Managed than it ll show this type of error..

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

Edited :- For testing, you have to test with different accounts.

Good luck.